# Ошибка компиляции C++ кода с Irrlicht библиотекой

Tags: c++, irrlicht

Я скомпилировал отдельно исходники Irrlicht (в source каталоге), затем создал Makefile где будет уже компилироваться мой файл на C++ и затем компоноваться вместе с библиотекой. Вот C++ код и Makefile:

```
IRRLICHT_FILES = /home/user/irrlicht-1.8.4/source/Irrlicht

COMPILED_FILES = $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/C3DSMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CAnimatedMeshHalfLife.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CAnimatedMeshMD2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CAnimatedMeshMD3.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CAnimatedMeshSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CAttributes.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CB3DMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CBillboardSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CBoneSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CBSPMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CBurningShader_RasterReference.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CCameraSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CColladaFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CColadaMeshWriter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CColorConverter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CCSMLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CCubeSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D8Driver.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D8NormalMapRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D8ParallaxMapRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D8ShaderMaterialRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D8Texture.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D9Driver.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D9HLSLMaterialRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D9NormalMapRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D9ParallaxMapRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D9ShaderMaterialRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CD3D9Texture.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CDefaultGUIElementFactory.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CDefaultSceneNodeAnimatorFactory.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CDefaultSceneNodeFactory.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CDepthBuffer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CDMFLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CDummyTransformationSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CEmptySceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CFileList.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CFileSystem.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CFPSCounter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGeometryCreator.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIButton.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUICheckBox.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIColorSelectDialog.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIComboBox.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIContextMenu.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIEditBox.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIEnvironment.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIFileOpenDialog.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIFont.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIImage.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIImageList.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIInOutFader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIListBox.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIMenu.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIMeshViewer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIMessageBox.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIModalScreen.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIScrollBar.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUISkin.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUISkin.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUISpriteBank.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIStaticText.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUITabControl.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUITable.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIToolBar.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUITreeView.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CGUIWindow.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImage.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderBMP.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderDDS.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderJPG.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderPCX.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderPNG.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderPPM.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderPSD.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderRGB.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderTGA.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageLoaderWAL.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageWriterBMP.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageWriterJPG.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageWriterPCX.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageWriterPNG.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageWriterPPM.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageWriterPSD.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CImageWriterTGA.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrDeviceConsole.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrDeviceFB.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrDeviceLinux.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrDeviceSDL.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrDeviceStub.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrDeviceWin32.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CIrrMeshWriter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CLightSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CLimitReadFile.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CLMTSMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CLogger.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CLWOMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMD2MeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMD3MeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMemoryFile.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMeshCache.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMeshManipulator.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMeshSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMetaTriangleSelector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMountPointReader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMS3DMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CMY3DMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CNPKReader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CNullDriver.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COBJMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COBJMeshWriter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COCTLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COctreeSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COctreeTriangleSelector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COgreMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COpenGLDriver.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COpenGLExtensionHandler.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COpenGLNormalMapRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COpenGLParallaxMapRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COpenGLShaderMaterialRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COpenGLSLMaterialRenderer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COpenGLTexture.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/COSOperator.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CPakReader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleAnimatedMeshSceneNodeEmitter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleAttractionAffector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleBoxEmitter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleCylinderEmitter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleFadeOutAffector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleGravityAffector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleMeshEmitter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticlePointEmitter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleRingEmitter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleRotationAffector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleScaleAffector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleSphereEmitter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CParticleSystemSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CPLYMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CPLYMeshWriter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CQ3LevelMesh.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CQuake3ShaderSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CReadFile.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneCollisionManager.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneLoaderIrr.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneManager.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorCameraFPS.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorCameraMaya.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorCollisionResponse.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorDelete.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorFlyCircle.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorFlyStraight.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorFollowSpline.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorRotation.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSceneNodeAnimatorTexture.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CShadowVolumeSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSkinnedMesh.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSkyBoxSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSkyDomeSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSMFMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSoftwareDriver.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSoftwareDriver2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSoftwareTexture.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSoftwareTexture2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSphereSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSTLMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CSTLMeshWriter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTarReader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTerrainSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTerrainTriangleSelector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTextSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRFlat.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRFlatWire.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRGouraud.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRGouraud2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRGouraudAlpha2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRGouraudAlphaNoZ2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRGouraudWire.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTriangleBBSelector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTriangleSelector.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRNormalMap.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRStencilShadow.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureBlend.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureDetailMap2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureFlat.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureFlatWire.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraud.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraud2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudAdd.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudAdd2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudAlpha.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudAlphaNoZ.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudNoZ.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudNoZ2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudVertexAlpha2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureGouraudWire.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureLightMap2_Add.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureLightMap2_M1.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureLightMap2_M2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureLightMap2_M4.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureLightMapGouraud2_M4.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CTRTextureWire2.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CVideoModeList.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CVolumeLightSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CWADReader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CWaterSurfaceSceneNode.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CWriteFile.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CXMeshFileLoader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CXMLReader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CXMLWriter.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CZBuffer.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/CZipReader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/IBurningShader.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/Irrlicht.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/irrXML.o $(IRRLICHT_FILES)/os.o


CPP_FILE = /home/user/irrlicht/experimental.cpp

all: experimental.o experimental

experimental.o: $(CPP_FILE)
    gcc -c -o experimental.o $(CPP_FILE)

experimental: $(COMPILED_FILES) $(CPP_FILE)
    gcc -o experimental $(COMPILED_FILES) $(CPP_FILE)
```

Но когда я ввожу команду make all, то мне выдается ошибка:

```
gcc -c -o experimental.o /home/user/irrlicht/experimental.cpp
g++ -c -o /home/user/irrlicht-1.8.4/source/Irrlicht/CAnimatedMeshMD2.o /home/user/irrlicht-1.8.4/source/Irrlicht/CAnimatedMeshMD2.cpp
/home/user/irrlicht-1.8.4/source/Irrlicht/CAnimatedMeshMD2.cpp:5:10: fatal error: IrrCompileConfig.h Нет такого файла или каталога
#include "IrrCompileConfig.h"
compilation terminated.
```

Почему там в инклуде путь к файлу неправильно указан? Он же находится в include каталоге, не в текущем!

Comment: А инклюды он откуда будет брать? Укажите где они лежат, проблема будет решена.

Comment: Что значит "в инклуде путь к файлу неправильно указан"? В `#include` вообще не принято указывать пути к файлам (кроме, разве что, локальных).

Comment: Ок, попробую указать, спасибо. @Ant, а как тогда компилятор узнает, где находится файл, если не в текущем каталоге? По-моему, по той то и причине ошибка происходит, странно что сами разработчики такой косяк сделали.